# In what situation does changed event trigger in loopback?

Tags: loopbackjs

/common/models/meetups.js

```
module.exports = function(Meetups) {
  Meetups.on('changed', function(inst) {
    console.log('--------------------------------------');
    console.log('model with id %s has been changed', inst.id);
    console.log(inst);
    console.log('--------------------------------------');
  });
}
```

I have a model Meetups and i want to listen for CUD(Create, Update and Delete) operations in the model and i listen for 'changed' event but adding, deleting document from the model didn't trigger the event?

Answer (score 1):

Loopback 3 does not support changed event any more. You can read more about similar question here:
[How to make Loopback models events work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40524616/how-to-make-loopback-models-events-work)

What you do have, are hooks:

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html

You should find your answer there

Answer (score 1):

This might be work for you

```
module.exports = function(Model) {
    Model.observe('before save', function(ctx, next) {
        console.log("here before save");
     })
}

  module.exports = function(Model) {
        Model.observe('after save', function(ctx, next) {
            console.log("here after save");
         })
    }
```